# html5 grid that always fit one page with sizeable grid-item count

Tags: html, css

I want to use a html5 grid for my artworks. The site is a one page layout. the grid should size itself according how many grid-items are on the site that it always fit on the screen. So the items get smaller as more items are in the grid. Below my existing code. I hope 1fr would do that job. But there is something else I miss but im pretty new and want bang my head against the keyboard as im trying to get it right for hours now. Hope someone can help. Otherwise i go for fixed grid like 4x4 and check width manually so it fits on the screen on full screen and just make a Button to show the next 4x4 items.

Thank you in advance!

cheers

```css
.dynamic-grid{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  grid-row-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 10% 25% 1fr;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  min-height: 300px;




}

.artwork{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 0.1vw;


}

.artwork > img{
  position: relative;

  max-width: 75%;
  object-fit: contain;




}

.info{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1em;

}
```

```html
<div id="dynamic" class="dynamic-grid">
  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, this way as more items will get into the grid it always creates the right amount of cells and size them to min 20% and max freespace.
So maximum 5 columns and rest append to a new row:

```
height: 100%;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20%, 1fr));
```

and the artwork image it self can not be bigger than height or width 100% of the grid-item:

```
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong :)

```css
.dynamic-grid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20%, 1fr));
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: silver;
}

.artwork {
  background-color: deepPink;
  padding: 2%;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 1vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.artwork > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;

}
```

```html
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <div id="dynamic" class="dynamic-grid">

    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #1 unispace kittens
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #2 unispace kittens
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #3 unispace kittens

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #4 unispace kittens
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #5 unispace kitten

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #6 unispace kitten

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #7 unispace kitten

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #8 unispace kitten
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #9 unispace kitten
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #10 unispace kitten
    </div>

    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #1 unispace kitten
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #2 unispace kitten
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #3 unispace kitten

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #4 unispace kitten
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #5 unispace kitten

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #6 unispace kitten

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #7 unispace kitten

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #8 unispace kitten
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #9 unispace kitten
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #10 unispace kitten
    </div>


    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #1 unispace kittens
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #2 unispace kittens
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #3 unispace kittens

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #4 unispace kittens
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #5 unispace kitten

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #6 unispace kitten

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #7 unispace kitten

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #8 unispace kitten
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #9 unispace kitten
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #10 unispace kitten
    </div>

    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #1 unispace kitten
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #2 unispace kitten
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #3 unispace kitten

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #4 unispace kitten
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #5 unispace kitten

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #6 unispace kitten

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #7 unispace kitten

    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #8 unispace kitten
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #9 unispace kitten
    </div>
    <div class="artwork">
      <img src="https://elasticbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/elasticbox-rocket2.png">
      #10 unispace kitten
    </div>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

grid elements **fr** dimension is different from the **fr** in flexbox.

Here it relates to the not used space after taking into account the space required for the elements.

A solution to your layout could be this one:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.dynamic-grid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 12.5%);
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  grid-row-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 10% 25% 1fr;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: silver;
}

.artwork {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 0.1vw;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.artwork>img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.info {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="dynamic" class="dynamic-grid">
  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="artwork">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Info Text
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: many thanks, i could figured it out. the hint with the height was very usefull. I got overwhelmed by css layout.  See my post below and btw cute cats in your work <3